# Apache HTTPD adding Full Hostname to Redirect - we want only path

Tags: apache

We want Apache HTTPD to redirect all traffic from `/` to `/cx`.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ "/cx"
```

We expect it to return the following header with a 301 response:

```
Location: /cx
```

Instead it returns:

```
Location: http://internalhostname/cx
```

Where `http://internalhostname` is whatever the incoming `Host:` request header contains.

We do not want this as our server is behind a reverse proxy and the client outside cannot handle `http://internalhostname`. This `internalhostname` is of course added to the request by the reverse proxy but that is as it should be.

Why is httpd adding the full hostname and how can we stop it?

Using `UseCanonicalName Off` or `UseCanonicalName On` makes no difference: the hostname is always added but with `On` it uses the `ServerName`.

Comment: Why not `RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ "http://external.example.com/cx"`?

Comment: Because we want our application to work behind a reverse proxy (externaldomain.com) AND be reachable/testable directly (internaldomain.com). Currently we can only run one or the other because it redirects both use cases to the same domain.

Comment: Any reverse proxy that doesn't forward the original host header should be fixing up redirects that include the internal hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've solved this by rewriting the Location header to remove prototcol, hostname and port:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ "/cx/"
Header edit Location "(^http[s]?://)([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)(:\d+)?/" "/"
```

Comment: There is a bugzilla issue for this already: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63357

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `RedirectMatch` directive with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/cx [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: HTTP_HOST is also the wrong value since the client-facing reverse proxy sets this to the internal domain name `Host: internalhosname` which would result in `Location: http://internalhostname/cx`. Surely there's a way to redirect without a hostname.